# Github push failing on authentication?

Tags: git

I've recently begun a new web project and am using Git.

I've had success cloning, adding, committing, pushing, you know the basics.
I was digging through docs on bypassing the credential step and I fear this is where the problem lies.

I had attempted this last week and I don't have details on what I had done unfortunately.

The error I'm experiencing is...

```
$ git push
Password for 'https://=@github.com':
```

When I enter the password, it returns a

```
fatal: Authentication failed
```

I've only ever used one password so I'm sure it's not a mismatch.

I've tried unsetting credential helpers with no luck already.
I've also tried wiping out the GIT tracking and recloning the repo, so my gut reaction is it's a global settings problem.

What stuck out to me was the `https://=@`...
I'm unclear to exactly what this path refers to though.

```
# ~/.gitconfig

[user]
    name = Joe Hillman
[gui]
    recentrepo = C:/Users/Joe/sandbox
    recentrepo = C:/Users/Joe/Projects/Scripting Projects
[credential] username = =
```

My email matched with the site so I went ahead and pulled it.
Credential settings stick out to me though being empty.
That may have been what I was mucking around with last week.

```
$ git remote -v

origin  https://github.com/littleredplanedesign/camareroFramework.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/littleredplanedesign/camareroFramework.git (push)
```

Apparently this problem was the blank credential area in the config.

I'm back up and running. Thanks for the assist on this as I wouldn't have guessed to check this file initially. I was looking at another config entirely.

Comment: Could you show the contents of your `~/.gitconfig` (assuming nothing sensitive)?

Comment: So that's literally a equals sign in the URL? Sounds like your remote is set up incorrectly. Try running `git remote -v`

Comment: Thanks, Ismali, Ajedi. It was the blank credential field in the config file that was jamming this up. I wouldn't have thought to look at this particular config so thanks for the assist here!

Answer (score 0):

The configuration option is explained in the [manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) like this:

> #### credential.username
>
> If no username is set for a network authentication, use this username by default. See credential..* below, and [gitcredentials(7)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html).

So by specifying this value, you are telling Git to always use that username to authenticate. As the value in your case was `=`, this was obviously not helpful.

You can remove that value by doing `git config --global --unset credential.username`.

The usual approach to provide a default username for would also probably be by specifying it in the URL, i.e. `https://username@github.com/user/repo.git`.